# A word to signify the scope of something

Tags: word-choice

As in:

> The impacts could be mental all to way to physical.

Where *mental* signifies the lower extremity and *physical* the upper extreme.

Comment: What's wrong with "scope" or one of its synonyms like "range" or "extent"?

Comment: encompass (v)- include in scope; include as part of something broader.

Answer (score 1):

*[gamut](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gamut?searchDictCode=all)* is a common word for this:

> The impacts run the gamut from mental to physical.

Answer (score 1):

The most common formulation of something like this in American English would be:

> The impacts **range** from mental all the way to physical.

See the second definition below.

```
range noun, often attributive \ˈrānj\
: a group or collection of different things or people that are usually similar in some way

: a series of numbers that includes the highest and lowest possible amounts

: the total amount of ability, knowledge, experience, etc., that a person has
```

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/range)

Answer (score 0):

**Range**--'Possible impacts range from mental, all the way to physical.'

Answer (score -2):

Tangibility (physical) is one word whose other extreme - intangibility (mental).

Update

http://www.athenaalliance.org/weblog/archives/2015/02/january-employment-in-tangible-and-intangible-prod.html - 'Tangible activities are primarily physical; intangible are primarily mental.'

Comment: I wouldn't say those particularly express mental or physical. Do you have any evidence to back up your claim?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include new information.